# How to design precisely timed remote data fetching algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, synchronization, fetch

There is a server that publishes some XML data every 5 seconds for GET fetch. The URL is simple and does not change, like `www.XXX.com/fetch-data`. The data is published in a loop every 5 seconds precisely, and IS NOT guaranteed to be unique every time (but does change quite often anyway). Apart from that, I can also fetch XML at `www.XXX.com/fetch-time`, where server time is stored, in *unix time* format. So, the fetch-time resolution is unfortunately just in seconds.

What I need is a way to synchronize my client code such that it fetches the data AS SOON AS POSSIBLE to when they are published. If I just naively fetch in a loop every 5 seconds, what might happen is that if I get really unlucky, my loop might start right before the server loop ends, so I will basically always end up with 5 second old data. I need a mechanism to get both server and client loops in tandem. Also, I need to compensate for lag (ping), so that the fetch request is sent actually a little before the server publishes new data.

The server code is proprietary and can't be changed, so all the hard stuff must be done by client. Also, there are many other questions about high-precision time measurements and sleep functions, so you can abstract from those and take them as granted. Any help with the algorithm would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you just use a long poll?

Comment: No luck, Poll the server with *short* intervals...

Comment: No, I'm afraid no long poll :-(

Comment: No way to predict lag.  If I want that data ASAP I would place a server as close to that server as I could.  Have your server push to to you.